# How do I compare several fields in an object to a queue of objects?

Tags: java, queue, comparator

I would like to compare an object to objects already in a queue.

I'm not sure if I should make the implement Comparable for my object or try to compare the items before they are added to the queue.  The items will be data from a reader, so the items will be coming pretty fast.  My queue has a limit of 10,000 items.  Once it reaches the max, it will start deleting the oldest item.

I started to extend my object with Comparable but I'm not sure if PriorityQueue is thread safe. So now I'm trying to see if I can use the peek function to look in the queue but my problem is that I need to compare several fields in each object.  I need to look at the tag number, date and device name. What would be the best way to do what I need to do?  Thanks!

code from example given:

```
@Component
public class TagInfoComparator implements Comparator<TagInfo>{

@Override
public int compare(TagInfo tag1, TagInfo tag2) {
    if(tag1.getEpc().equals(tag2.getEpc())){
        if(tag1.getIpaddr().equals(tag2.getIpaddr())){
            return tag1.getTimestamp().compareTo(tag2.getTimestamp());
        }
        return tag1.getIpaddr().compareTo(tag2.getIpaddr());
    }
    return tag1.getEpc().compareTo(tag2.getEpc());
}

}
```

Here is my updated code for the comparator.  I have this:

```
public static PriorityBlockingQueue<TagInfo> TagBuffer2=new
```

PriorityBlockingQueue(10000,new TagInfoComparator());

in my code. Then I say: 
    TagBuffer2.add(tag);

This is the error I receive after that.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rfidreader.async.model.TagInfo cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:489)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.add(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:463)
at com.rfidreader.async.model.CSLReader.StartInventory(CSLReader.java:489)
at com.rfidreader.async.AsyncRfidpringApplication.lambda$4(AsyncRfidpringApplication.java:258)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to compare several fields? How will the elements in the queue be sorted?

Comment: Do you want to determine if a duplicate object is already in the queue? Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: OK sorry if my question is not clear.  I have object, let's say its Team.  Team has tag number, date, device name, address, phone number.  The queue contains Team objects up to 10,000.  The Team objects are read from reader continuously.  When the team objects are read by a reader, need to see if the team object was inserted in the queue already by comparing the tag number, date and device name.  If there is team object with same tag number/device name, I want to see if the date was less than 10 min before now.  If so, then I don't want to add it to the queue, else, I will add it. @JimMischel

Comment: You're probably better off maintaining a separate map that tells you what Team objects are in the queue. That way, you can quickly look in the map. Otherwise, you would have to scan the queue on every insert. You will have to maintain the map: adding teams when they're inserted into the queue, and removing them from the map when they are removed from the queue.

Comment: So it's easier to use a map rather than a Queue? @JimMischel

Comment: You need both: the queue to keep the jobs in the right order, and the map to tell you what's in the queue. You could do it with just the queue, but doing so means that you would have to search all of the items in the queue sequentially whenever you wanted to insert. Using the map, you can determine with a single lookup whether an item is in the queue.

Comment: OK....I remove the first item in the queue when I reach 10,000.  How can I remove the first item in a map?

Comment: You don't remove the first item in the map. You use the item in the map that corresponds to the key of the item you removed from the queue.

Comment: @JimMischel How would I compare the dates in the map with the item I want to add to the queue?